# pandas.to_datetime is off by one hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have some data recorded with timestamps using `time.time()`. I want to evaluate the data using `pandas` and convert the timestamps to datetime objects for better handling. However, when I try, all my timing data is off by one hour. This example reproduces the issue on my machine:

```py
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

origin = dt.datetime(2024, 1, 15).timestamp()
timestamps = [origin + 3600 * i for i in range(10)]

print([dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).isoformat() for t in timestamps])
print(pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s'))
```

Output:

```
['2024-01-15T00:00:00', '2024-01-15T01:00:00', '2024-01-15T02:00:00', '2024-01-15T03:00:00', '2024-01-15T04:00:00', '2024-01-15T05:00:00', '2024-01-15T06:00:00', '2024-01-15T07:00:00', '2024-01-15T08:00:00', '2024-01-15T09:00:00']
DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-14 23:00:00', '2024-01-15 00:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 01:00:00', '2024-01-15 02:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 03:00:00', '2024-01-15 04:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 05:00:00', '2024-01-15 06:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 07:00:00', '2024-01-15 08:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I am guessing that this has something to do with my timezone (I'm in UTC+1) but I'm confused as to how I should deal with this. If possible, I want to avoid explicitly specifying timezones and such (though I will do it if necessary). I want to just get the same times as I get with `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp()`. How do I do this?

Comment: Not explicitly setting timezones (creating so-called naive datetime objects) should be avoided as it leads to errors like this.  Always set your timezone (usually UTC when you do not care for a specific timezone) to have timezone aware datetime objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert.html) to shift your datetime:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-15 00:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-15 01:00:00+01:00',
               '2024-01-15 02:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-15 03:00:00+01:00',
               '2024-01-15 04:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-15 05:00:00+01:00',
               '2024-01-15 06:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-15 07:00:00+01:00',
               '2024-01-15 08:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-15 09:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Paris]', freq=None)
```

You can replace `Europe/Paris` with `Etc/GMT-1` or `UTC+01:00`

If you want to convert as naive timezone without lag, you can chain with `tz_localize` to remove timezone information:

```
>>> (pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s', utc=True)
       .tz_convert('UTC+01:00')
       .tz_localize(None))

DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-15 00:00:00', '2024-01-15 01:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 02:00:00', '2024-01-15 03:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 04:00:00', '2024-01-15 05:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 06:00:00', '2024-01-15 07:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 08:00:00', '2024-01-15 09:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

It all depends on the meaning you give to your `timestamps` (naive or timezone aware)

If `time.time()` doesn't return the same value as `pd.Timestamp().now()`, you have to consider to use timezone to get the local time:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(time.time(), unit='s')
2024-01-15 16:12:49.276476672

>>> print(pd.Timestamp.now())
2024-01-15 17:12:49.276847
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is not with pandas but with the incorrect use of the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

You should specify that you are using an UTC datetime when creating the origin, otherwise this will use your timezone:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

origin = dt.datetime(2024, 1, 15, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).timestamp()

timestamps = [origin + 3600 * i for i in range(10)]

print(pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s'))
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-15 00:00:00', '2024-01-15 01:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 02:00:00', '2024-01-15 03:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 04:00:00', '2024-01-15 05:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 06:00:00', '2024-01-15 07:00:00',
               '2024-01-15 08:00:00', '2024-01-15 09:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Likewise:

```
print([dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(t, dt.timezone.utc).isoformat()
       for t in timestamps])
```

Output:

```
['2024-01-15T00:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T01:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T02:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T03:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T04:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T05:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T06:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T07:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T08:00:00+00:00',
 '2024-01-15T09:00:00+00:00']
```

Comment: _"Your issue is not with pandas but with the incorrect use of the `datetime` module."_ I'm not sure I agree with that assessment. As I wrote in my question, I'm using `time.time()` to create the timestamp in my real use case. I just used `datetime` here to get a reproducible example. _"You should specify that you are using an UTC datetime when creating the origin, otherwise this will use your timezone"_ And that is exactly what I want. What got me tangled is that the default behavior of `pd.to_datetime` does not match `datetime`'s, where the latter is the desired one.

Comment: @schtandard it depends on what you want in the end. Should your `2024-01-15 00:00:00` be the midnight time in UTC or in your timezone?

Comment: Of my timezone. I don't know if there is any consensus on this (probably not, which is why naive datetime objects are avoided) but this seems to me to be the natural way to naively interpret that string. (And `datetime` seems to agree, while `pandas` does not.)

Comment: Pandas will set the timezone as UTC if you provide none (and request a timezone aware timestamp). For instance `pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s', utc=True)` will give you a `DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-14 23:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)`. Which is the correct time since it's UTC and you defined yours as UTC+1. To force the display to your timezone use @Corralien's approach. Or, programmatically: `import time ; pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert(time.tzname[0])`